# Unique index not based on words order?

Tags: mysql, unique

Is it possibile to have a mysql UNIQUE index on a varchar field not based on the words order?

I mean if there is a row with `key1 key2`, and I try to insert `key2 key1` mysql should throw an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this effect by adding before insert and before update triggers to the table; they could check whether a row with the fields reversed exists or not before inserting/updating if it doesn't, or forcing an error if it does.

See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the indexed to UNIQUE, you will not be able to enter the **identical** data twice - numbers, words or otherwise.

If you wish to achieve something otherwise, you'll have to set a new non-unique field in your database then you'll be able achieve it using external code and queries (PHP, C#).

Answer (score 0):

Create a trigger to do this.

i.e.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name BEFORE INSERT ON table_name
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE col2=NEW.col1 OR col1=NEW.col2) <> 0)
   THEN
     CALL this_procedure_does_not_exist();
   END IF
END
```